# tensor flow using uninitialized value

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, init, tensor

here is my code:

```
W_conv1 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([3,3,3,21], stddev=0.1), name = 'W')
b_conv1 = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=[21]))
W_conv2 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([3,3,21,63], stddev=0.1), name = 'W')
b_conv2 = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=[63]))

sess = tf.Session()
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
init_lo = tf.local_variables_initializer()
sess.run(init_lo)
sess.run(init)

h_conv1 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(x_, W_conv1) + b_conv1) 
h_conv2 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(h_conv1, W_conv2) + b_conv2)
sess.run(h_conv2)
```

the error was:

```
Caused by op u'Variable_2/read', defined at:
File "7.py", line 78, in <module>
b_conv2 = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=[63]))
File "/home/mcuee/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variables.py", line 197, in __init__
expected_shape=expected_shape)
File "/home/mcuee/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variables.py", line 316, in _init_from_args
self._snapshot = array_ops.identity(self._variable, name="read")
File "/home/mcuee/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_array_ops.py", line 1338, in identity
result = _op_def_lib.apply_op("Identity", input=input, name=name)
File "/home/mcuee/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 768, in apply_op
op_def=op_def)
File "/home/mcuee/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2336, in create_op
original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)
File "/home/mcuee/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1228, in __init__
self._traceback = _extract_stack()

FailedPreconditionError (see above for traceback): Attempting to use   uninitialized value Variable_2
 [[Node: Variable_2/read = Identity[T=DT_FLOAT, _class=["loc:@Variable_2"], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](Variable_2)]]
```

I run my code ,and I init the value, and something goes wrong, I don't know why, and how to deal with it. it's my second time to run the code, I just add something into it, but the convolution layer wasn't change anything. Is the problem with another code?

Comment: I was using placeholder and feed_dict, I didn't shows.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the call to `conv2d` is adding more variables. If `conv2d` in your code snippet is shorthand for `tf.layers.conv2d`, then that will be the case.

You want to initialize all the variables after defining them, so something like:

```
W_conv1 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([3,3,3,21], stddev=0.1), name = 'W')
b_conv1 = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=[21]))
W_conv2 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([3,3,21,63], stddev=0.1), name = 'W')
b_conv2 = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=[63]))

sess = tf.Session()


h_conv1 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(x_, W_conv1) + b_conv1) 
h_conv2 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(h_conv1, W_conv2) + b_conv2)

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
init_lo = tf.local_variables_initializer()
sess.run(init_lo)
sess.run(init)

sess.run(h_conv2)
```

Holpe that helps.